# How to execute Imagemagick in PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick, exec

I found a very helpful post on here about cropping images in a circle. However, when I try to execute the imagemagick script using exec in PHP, I'm getting no results. I've checked to make sure the directories have the correct permissions and such. Is there a step I'm missing?

Any insight would be much appreciated. Here's what my script looks like:

$run = exec('convert -size 200x200 xc:none -fill daisy.jpg -draw "circle 100,100 100,1" uploads/new.png');

Edit: Imagemagick is installed.

Answer (score 7):

```
$out=array();
$err = 0;
$run = exec('convert -size 200x200 xc:none -fill daisy.jpg -draw "circle 100,100 100,1" uploads/new.png',$out,$err);
echo implode ("<br>",$out);
print_r($err);
print_r($run);
```

what would it say?

Comment: It says "127" which apparently means there is something wrong with the path.

Comment: @erik just use absolute paths. both to the source and resulting picture