# Turning photo into cartoon using PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick

Most probably using ImageMagick - how to turn photo into "cartoon"?
Here's what I mean:

[image]

(not sure, that step 2 is necessary).

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Paul did you find the answer for "Step2"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A question [asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058224/creation-of-edge-detection-based-image-in-php) shows some ImageMagick approaches to get to step 2.

As for step 3, there is a ImageMagick-based application named [G'Mic](http://gmic.sourceforge.net/gallery.shtml) that provides some advanced multi-step filters. The gallery shows some results that come close. However, it is in C++ so you'll probably need to compile it on your system.

Also, Googling for <kbd>Imagemagick</kbd> <kbd>Cartoonify</kbd> yields some example scripts that are worth checking out.

Also, make sure you dig into the [ImageMagick examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/) page, one of the greatest IM resources around.

That said, I doubt whether it is possible to build a IM-based solution  that works as well as the cartoonifier you show. IM is hugely powerful, but may not have the necessary degree of detailed control, individual programming and vectorization functions. But the basic functionality is possible.

Comment: Hi peeka, can we do the "Step2" in objectivec?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do this using php with some image editing library,
you'll need a graphic editing software like photoshop i am sure there are many tutorials for this thing out there

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I'm looking for solution in PHP ;) Hopefully there are some functions which make this possible using e.g. ImageMagick

Comment: The middle 'charcoal' effect is completely possible with ImageMagick. Although, I'm not sure about step 3.

Comment: @ Russell Dias: It is not giving same Image using "Charcoal" .