# Convert image to pencil drawing (Not pencil sketch) using imagemagick

Tags: python, imagemagick

I need an application which converts any image to pencil drawing (Not sketch ) like artist does. Exactly like the step2 from step 1 [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062365/turning-photo-into-cartoon-using-php). I have tried the following options.

- [Tried the charcol effect + color in effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062365/turning-photo-into-cartoon-using-php) but it only fits perfectly for sharp color change images. But mine is mostly not.
- [Tried canny edge detector](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/transform/#canny) and inverting the image: But not getting desired output as it changes according to the clarity of the image.
- [Tried the photo copy example here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/photos/#color-in) : This suites the purpose but I don't want the shade effect and unwanted pixel dots just need proper outline only.

1- What is the best approach for my requirement ?

2- What are we specifying with the argument string `0x1+10%+20%` in cany detection ?

3- How can I remove the pencil shades in photocopy and just get the important outline only ?

4- Is there any other image editing tools out there which fits best ?

Answer (score 5):

I hope the following helps. The functions used below are readily available in OpenCV. You can give it a try.

This is the image I am using for reference:

[image]

Pencil Sketching:

```
sketch_gray, sketch_color = cv2.pencilSketch(img, sigma_s=60, sigma_r=0.07, shade_factor=0.05)
```

Output of `sketch_gray`, which is the pencil sketch of the gray scale image:

[image]

Output of `sketch_color`, which is the pencil sketch of the color image:

[image]

You can limit the amount of shade in the output by varying the `shade_factor` in the function `cv2.pencilSketch`.

And as a bonus `cv2.stylization`:

```
stylize = cv2.stylization(img, sigma_s=60, sigma_r=0.07)
```

[image]

Comment: You can obtain **pencil drawing** by varying the `shade_factor` as mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @Jeru Luke : How about a passport size photograph work with this ? I will switch from image magick to opencv after waiting few more replies.

Comment: @BillGoldberg I have never tried it. Why not give it a shot? Just vary the `shade_factor` as mentioned. :)