# Edge Detection of Image in iPhone Using Image Magick

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, imagemagick

I want to convert RGB image into Below Image. I am using ImageMagick Library . I want help to know that by which functions i can convert in Original Image into Image-2. Here is below two images. I would like to use Only ImageMagick Library. I would like to do Image Processing simillar to this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062365/turning-photo-into-cartoon-using-php) in Objective C.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

@Apoorv i dont know any thing about but if you just want edge detection may be you can use openCV instead.

here is the link for some of the source code and tutorials of how to detect edge in iphone using openCV

[iPhone and OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348040/iphone-and-opencv)

http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut5.html

here is a sample project that i have created in iphone using openCV

original image

[image]

image after edge detection.

[image]

Comment: Yes. I have already use OpenCV. But I want converted image. In that image when there is difference beetween two color it shows as black border. This is not simple edge detection.

Comment: Can you tell your requirements more clearly. about the `converted image` and `difference beetween two color it shows as black border`

Comment: I want to do like this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062365/turning-photo-into-cartoon-using-php

Comment: Hi Robin In the above the output shows with black and gray lines....i want white background with black lines.. Plz guide me

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to be sure if that image was even generated with Image Magick. But if you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058224/creation-of-edge-detection-based-image-in-php/4058233#4058233), it's worth taking a look at the [charcoal filter](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/photos/#charcoal):

```
convert holocaust_sm.jpg -charcoal 5 charcoal.gif
```

My suggestion is that you also experiment with [thresholds](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#threshold), and take a look at the [Children's Color-In Outline Image](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/photos/#color-in) example, since I believe it wasn't a single filter that achieved that effect (assuming it was generated by IM).

After researching for a while I believe that an effect like the one you are looking for could be achieved through a mixture of several filters. You must check [this page](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php), which presents a huge collection of cool effects using IM.

This is my attempt:

```
convert ms8nP.png -colorspace Gray -blur 0x.7 -negate -edge 2 -negate -threshold 40% -blur 0x.5 out.png
```

Comment: After applying threshold with 40% values, it gives white image.In magickwand function is:MagickThresholdImage(magick_wand, 40);

Comment: Do you have any idea to implement step 3 of this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062365/turning-photo-into-cartoon-using-php

Comment: I might, but that's another question and I'll be happy to answer it in another thread.