# Draw color on country (Mapkit) when it is selected

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mapkit

[image]

[image]

I want to color the country on selection of the country from a tableView. Can you help me please?

Comment: I don't think `MapKit` has any in-built support for it, nor can you make changes to it. At the most, you could probably show images on top of the map to give the illusion of a selection but I'm still not sure of it. The best way would be to use pins.

Comment: can anyone suggest me any api to get boundary of the country???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your case, let me give you a heads up that this would require edge detection (so if you haven't done that before, it will take a LONG time), though not lots of it and the following is just one way of approaching this problem:

1) Take out an image context from the map you have.

2) Apply relevant [edge detection algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) in the area you want and use a bright color to differentiate. Note that this way, the inside would not be colored and I can't tell you for sure if that's possible or not.

3) Add that context as a subView on top of the map.

Also take a look at the [Quartz 2D programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html) for more tips.

I would suggest something different, though. Keep pre-stored images for all the possibilities and just put a `UIImageView` with that as its image in front of the map - this will save you a lot of headache.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut5.html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037502/edge-detection-of-image-in-iphone-using-image-magick)

Comment: Due to shortage of time Now I have decided to take a few boundary coordinates of the country and then put an MKpolygenView over the map.

Comment: Find `MapKit` [overlays here](http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html)

Comment: @AnilKothari: Do you know any way to get boundary coordinates of a country?

Comment: try the above written procedure by typical flow

Comment: Why would you need edge detection? You don't have to get the shapes of the countries from the maps: Those are known and shapefiles for the world can be found. you 'only' have to put the right overlay over the map.

Comment: I believe @PanMan's solution is easier, simply overlay a country's image over the map using the lat-long and current map zoom level. That would require mapping every country's lat-long bounds with current location being shown on map