# Measure the size of an object with camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing

I need to do an method which measure the object from a photo... I mean that I can compare the object with the size from a card to get the size from object, but I don't know how to compare this... Any idea?

Here is how I am taking the picture

```
- (IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender {
// Create image picker controller
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

// Set source to the camera
imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

// Delegate is self
imagePicker.delegate = self;

// Allow editing of image ?
imagePicker.allowsImageEditing = NO;

// Show image picker
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

  }

       - (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
     {
UIAlertView *alert;

// Unable to save the image
if (error)
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                       message:@"Unable to save image to Photo Album."
                                      delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
else // All is well
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success"
                                       message:@"Image saved to Photo Album."
                                      delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
 }
```

Comment: The code you have shown is how you call the image picker. How does that relate to your question?

Comment: yes, I need take this image and get the width and height from a defined area

Comment: If I understand you correctly then you will have to perform some image processing in order to identify this area, get its size and convert that to some real world measures.

Comment: @HermannKlecker yes, but I don't know how to do this..

Comment: Neither do I. And if I would then I would sell my high profiled consultancy on image processing. If I were you I would start with some edge detection and based on the shape of the card and its contents try to identifiy which of the rectangular (4 edges - depending on perspective not nessessarily rectangualr in the image) of the image corresponds with the card - if any. And then go from there.

Comment: Yes, I wanna to base of the card...but I don't know how to check how many cards have space for in this photo

Answer (score 3):

Here's a site with some ios ported [image processing algorithms](http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/).  If you can detect the outer edges of the image and some reference object (and know that they are at the same depth), you should be able to approximate size.

EDIT - Turns out there's no code at that link.  [Here's an SO answer about using OpenCV to do edge detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037502/edge-detection-of-image-in-iphone-using-image-magick).  Anyway, the point is, you need image processing to pull measurable features from the photo.